# Can't save records to List of class in Blazor app

Tags: c#, .net, oop, blazor

I have class storing users names:

```
    public class PlayersManager
    {
        public string tableId;
        public string whitePlayer;
        public string blackPlayer;
    }
```

I am using it in my Hub by this:

```
 private readonly TableManager tableManager;
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;
        private readonly List<PlayersManager> playersTable;
        public MultiplayerHub(TableManager tableManager, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            this.tableManager = tableManager;
            this.userManager = userManager;
            this.playersTable = new List<PlayersManager>();
        }
.
.
.
   public async Task AddWhitePlayer(string tableId, string userName)
        {
            var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);

                PlayersManager man = new PlayersManager();
                man.tableId = tableId;
                man.whitePlayer = userName;
                playersTable.Add(man);
                await Clients.GroupExcept(tableId, Context.ConnectionId).SendAsync("Works");

        }
        public async Task AddBlackPlayer(string tableId, string userName)
        {
            var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);

            var table = playersTable.FirstOrDefault(a => a.tableId == tableId);

            table.blackPlayer = userName;
        }
```

This is the way Im saving data (razor page):

```
 protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        if (IsWhitePlayer)
        {
            whitePlayer = playerName;
            HubConnection.SendAsync("AddWhitePlayer", TableId, playerName);
        }

        if (!IsWhitePlayer)
        {
            blackPlayer = playerName;
            HubConnection.SendAsync("AddBlackPlayer", TableId, playerName);
        }
```

Problem is that when function AddWhitePlayers is used, everything works. When I made breakpoint here:

```
                await Clients.GroupExcept(tableId, Context.ConnectionId).SendAsync("Works");
```

I can see that list PlayersTable and my "man" variable is not null. So it looks like record got saved to list.
But after that when function AddBlackPlayer is used im getting error that table is null. Can someone explain me why and how can I fix it?

Comment: How is `OnInitialized` getting called and where is `IsWhitePlayer` set? Make sure `this.playersTable = new List<PlayersManager>();` is not hit between calls or your table will get reset.

Comment: IsWhitePlayer is sent as [Parameter] of page, OnInitialized is overrided method automatically turned on with page start.